# Is it possible to send some arguments to monkeyrunner script

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I start my monkeyrunner script like this

```
monkeyrunner my_script
```

but I want to pass some arguments for example like this

```
monkeyrunner my_script -n 100
```

and how can I read this value inside the my_script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the script arguments in `sys.argv` list:

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

import sys

print sys.argv
```

Comment: do you have any ideas what is the syntax for for loop in monkeyrunner script ? I couldn't find anywhere . . .

Answer (score 1):

you can use [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) as well.Treat monkeyrunner code as  normal python.

```
import optparse
options = optparse.OptionParser()
options.add_option("--count", action="store", type="string", dest="count")
opt, args = options.parse_args()
n=opt.count
```

You can add any number of arguments in convenient way.

Comment: I found this "Deprecated since version 2.7: The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the argparse module."

Comment: hey, you are right.thanks for remembering. but still we can use.i pasted a part of my used code.But in you case you can start with "argparse"

Comment: Unfortunately monkeyrunner is not happy with _argparse_ module: `ImportError: No module named argparse`

Comment: monkeyrunner is running a version of jython which supports through python 2.7, which is why you can't use argparse